# MVC4 - Relationship between a View and a Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having difficulty grasping the concept of MVC within .NET. I'm creating a basic Blog application, mainly to gain insight and skills with MVC. I just don't quite get some of it. The part I am currently unclear about is the relationship between a Controller and View. It would clear the matter up if someone would answer me this.

I have a View called TestA which corresponds to my Controller ControllerTestA. Now I've added the following inside the ControllerTestA.

```
public ActionResult TestA (){ //do something }
```

Now I need to know if all my postbacks in whatever form from view TestA will have to go through my TestA Controller method. So essentially I could have different postback with different parameters for different reasons. Some in use with one postback and others in use for another. Is that how it is done?

Would love some assistance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Postback" in MVC. In contrast to WebForms, a view only renders HTML to be sent to the browser. As soon as any type of request is issued by the browser, it goes to the controller, not to the view.

As for the relationships:

- If you define a `TestAController` (note: Not "ControllerTestA"), it serves the "/TestA/*" URL's. If you have a method `TestA` in there it will serve "/TestA/TestA".
- If your method returns `View(someModel)` it will look for a view named `TestA.cshtml`/`TestA.aspx`, named like your method, within a folder `Views\TestA` (named like your controller, without the "Controller" suffix)
- The view will render the HTML based on the `someModel` passed by the controller.
- Within the view you may call other URL's or post data to some. This closes the circle.

As for the parameters or overloads, there are some restrictions:

- You can define overloads for GET vs. POST vs. PUT vs. DELETE. You will need to annotate the methods with the according attributes though.
- However you cannot define multiple overloads of the same method name for POSTs with different sets of parameters. You will need to make your POST method signature such that parameters can or cannot be sent to the server:

Example:

```
public ActionResult TestA(
    string someOptionalParameter, int? someOtherOptionalParam)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someOptionalParameter)) { ... }
    if (someOtherOptionalParam == null) { ... }
}
```

The model-mapper will set your parameters to `null` if they are not posted to the server.

Like Khalid already mentioned - you should not mix up the concepts of MVC and WebForms. They are very different. MVC has no such thing as a "view state" which could be posted to the server. It has no WebForm-like lifecycle for the ASPX (or CSHTML) pages.

Comment: This is what I have done which seems to work ok. I don't want to modify the URL I want it to be the same.  `public ActionResult TestA(int id, string title){
            ViewData["id"] = id; return View(_repository);
        }[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestA(string username)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { return RedirectToAction("TestA"); }
            return View();}` So I got this code to work yet it feels like I'm doing exactly what you said dont. I think I'm overloading a POST request with differing parameters. Yet it works.

Comment: @user303695: What I was trying to say is that you *can* overload the method and have one GET and one POST version (as you do), but you cannot have two POST overloads of the same method - does that answer your question of "essentially I could have different postback with different parameters for different reasons. Some in use with one postback and others in use for another"?

Comment: @user3036965: On a "side-track" - you pass a repository to the view. This creates the impression that your view might do to much and your controller merely forwards the request to the view. The idea of MVC is that the controller contains all the control flow logic (contact repositor, get or modify model, decide what to do next etc.) and merely uses the view to render a response. This is one of the big differences to WebForms. So the only thing you pass to the view should be data (the "model") and possibly some view options.

Comment: Silly me it is a GET and a POST and not two posts. I should have realised this. Thanks for all of your help. You have given me alot of sound advice here which I can now carry forward.

Comment: Thanks for the sidenote chiccodoro. I was able to refine my understanding of MVC and make changes to ensure that only model is passed directly to view. So it really helped.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a crucial part of the relationship here, which is routing. You are speaking in terms of WebForms using terms like **Postback**; don't do that because you'll end up confusing yourself.

The best way to think about MVC is in **Requests** and **Responses**.

Let's look at how a request (high level) happens in an MVC application.

### Request

1. Request hits the server with a url ex. /hello/world
2. That url is used to match any entries in your route table
3. When a match is found, that route defines basic values like what *controller* and *action* should be called.
4. The controller is created, and that action is called with the route values and other request properties (querystring, session, etc...).

### Response

1. We are now in the controller action, run the code you need to fulfill the request
2. Pass the data to the View
3. The view is determined by convention and your **ViewEngine**
4. The view is then rendered and written to the response.
5. The request/response is finished.

### Note

This whole process is determined by the route, and the relationship between the controller and view are trivial. Where the form is posted to is determined by you in the view by using helper methods that determine what **route** to hit in the next **request/response** flow.

Some Helper Methods.

```
@Url.Action("index", "home");
@Html.ActionLink("index", "home")
@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "home")) { }
```

To sum it all up, the relationship between the controller action and view is really facilitate by your routes. Once you have a grasp of how to create them, then you will better understand how to manage the interaction of your application. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form in a view, then that form has a url to which it will post to. This URL is  in the Html.BeginForm method in your view.

The form will then be posted to the appropriate controller methond in the approoriate controller

So if BeginForm starts like this:

> using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Product"

Then the action method "AddProduct" in the controller Product (ProductController is the class name) will be called.